# What is the correct verb form in "An increasing number of degrees (offer) online"?

Tags: verbs

I was asked to write this sentence with the correct form of verb in paranenthes:

An increasing number of degrees.....(offer) online.

What is the correct for ? Offered or Offering ? And why?

Comment: Neither of those alternatives makes a complete sentence. Institutions offer the degrees; the degrees don't offer anything. It has to be the passive _are offered_.

Comment: *An increasing number of degrees ARE **offered** online* - or [more idiomatically,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+offered+online%2Care+available+online&year_start=1999&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20offered%20online%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20available%20online%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20offered%20online%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20available%20online%3B%2Cc0) *...are **available** online*.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those alternatives makes a complete sentence. Institutions offer the degrees; the degrees don't offer anything. It has to be the passive *are offered.* (Kate) — or more idiomatically, ...[are available online](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20offered%20online%2Care%20available%20online&year_start=1999&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20offered%20online%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20available%20online%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20offered%20online%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20available%20online%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: comment to answer conversion